# A noun for phenomenon experienced by wave-particle duality

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology, nouns

We have known for centuries that elementary particles exhibit both wave and particle properties. Does the English Language have a word that describes this wave-particle duality?

Comment: It's been argued about for centuries, whether it's been _known_ for that long is another matter (or is it another wave?). You might do better asking this question on a quantum physics site.

Comment: Words that physicists have used for wave-particle duality are *"complementarity"* and *"quantum"*. To get a better answer, you might need tob e more specific.

Comment: I imagine you are looking for a non-specialized answer that might be used by a lay person. like "Certs - it's a breath mint; it's a candy mint; it's two mints in one!"  ? Otherwise, physicists call is "duality", which you already know.

Comment: This is a question for the Physics forum. As English is the predominant and defacto language of Science and technology since the atom bomb, and physicists and engineers have since been compelled to maintain a workable English vocabulary - the Physics forum should be consulted. If Physicists do not have any other term than duality, then it must be because of the huge disagreements about the fundamentals underlying the phenomenon, rather than lacking any other terminology for it.

Comment: @Blessed Geek: as I said above, the technical term physicists use for this is [complementarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementarity_%28physics%29). I see no reason why physicists need more words for this, or why there should be any relation between the number of words physicists have for a phenomenon and the amount of disagreement they have about it. Physicists have only one word for an electron, and they all agree that electrons exist.

Comment: Duality is a member of the set of phenomenon under the cover of complementarity.

Answer (score 1):

A common word would be **schizophrenic** which means (from [Dictionary.com)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/schizophrenic)

> 2. a state characterized by the coexistence of contradictory or incompatible elements.

Even among physicists, where duality might appear to be a casually accepted fact, they might fall back on words like *schizophrenic*, just to recognize the weirdness of the concept.

From The New York Time, *[Physics Awaits New Options as Standard Model Idles](http://www.nytimes.com/2006/07/04/science/04phys.html?pagewanted=print&_r=0)*, by Dennis Overbye, July 4, 2006:

> It happened this spring when two teams of physicists at Fermilab succeeded in measuring a particularly odd schizophrenic particle, known as the strange neutral B meson, that flips back and forth between being itself and its own opposite antiparticle three trillion times a second. Weird as that behavior is, it was right on the money as predicted by the Standard Model.

Machando and Pleitez, from the Institute for Theoretical Physics in Brazil, wrote a paper in March 2011 titled *Schizophrenic Active Neutrinos and Exotic Sterile Neutrinos*, carrying the medical metaphor further. The paper itself is indecipherable to a layman (including me), so I won't quote more than the title.

Comment: Well ... *"schizophrenic neutrinos"* behave quite a bit weirder than being waves and particles at the same time; they're Dirac and Majorana fermions at the same time.